# How to select sequential elements in xpath?

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have this XML:

```
<body>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <a id = "1"></a>
    <a id = "2"></a>
    <a id = "3"></a>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <a id = "4"></a>
    <a id = "5"></a>
    <a id = "6"></a>
</body>
```

Given the element `//div[id='1']` how do I select "it's" `<a>` elements (Ids from 1 to 3) but exclude `<a>` elements with id 4 or higher, since they appear after `<div id='2'>`

Comment: Your HTML shows the `<div>`s to be closed immediately, thus the `<a>` elements are not "it's". Is that intended or wrongly formatted?

Comment: format fixed, you were right. In my mind they were related but in reallity they aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
//div[@id='1']/following-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::div[1][@id='1']]
```

The XPath basically select `a` after `div[@id='1']` where nearest preceding sibling `div` element is the `div[@id='1']`. Or maybe the following simpler XPath is enough :

```
//a[preceding-sibling::div[1][@id='1']]
```

Comment: You probably don't need `div[1]`, just `div`.

Comment: Without `[1]` *all* `a` after `div[@id='1']` will be returned, including those after `div[@id='1']` : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/baf966d604d50cb68be3a8a1f8dd7f6a

Comment: oops, I meant *"including those after `div[@id='2']`"*. Anyway, you are welcome :)